# Appending row to Pandas DataFrame adds 0 column

Tags: python, pandas, append, dataframe

I'm creating a Pandas DataFrame to store data. Unfortunately, I can't know the number of rows of data that I'll have ahead  of time. So my approach has been the following.

First, I declare an empty DataFrame.

```
df = DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Then, I append a row of missing values.

```
df = df.append([None] * 2, ignore_index=True)
```

Finally, I can insert values into this DataFrame one cell at a time. (Why I have to do this one cell at a time is a long story.)

```
df['col1'][0] = 3.28
```

This approach works perfectly fine, with the exception that the append statement inserts an additional column to my DataFrame. At the end of the process the output I see when I type `df` looks like this (with 100 rows of data).

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0            0  non-null values
col1         100  non-null values
col2         100  non-null values
```

`df.head()` looks like this.

```
      0   col1   col2
0  None   3.28      1
1  None      1      0
2  None      1      0
3  None      1      0
4  None      1      1
```

**Any thoughts on what is causing this `0` column to appear in my DataFrame?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The append is trying to append a column to your dataframe.  The column it is trying to append is not named and has two None/Nan elements in it which pandas will name (by default) as column named 0.

In order to do this successfully, the column names coming into the append for the data frame must be consistent with the current data frame column names or else new columns will be created (by default)

```
#you need to explicitly name the columns of the incoming parameter in the append statement
df = DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
print df.append(Series([None]*2, index=['col1','col2']), ignore_index=True)


#as an aside

df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
dfRowImproper = [1,2,3,4]
#dfRowProper = DataFrame(arange(4)+1,columns=['A','B','C','D']) #will not work!!! because arange returns a vector, whereas DataFrame expect a matrix/array#
dfRowProper = DataFrame([arange(4)+1],columns=['A','B','C','D']) #will work


print df.append(dfRowImproper) #will make the 0 named column with 4 additional rows defined on this column

print df.append(dfRowProper) #will work as you would like as the column names are consistent

print df.append(DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,4))) #will define four additional columns to the df with 4 additional rows


print df.append(Series(dfRow,index=['A','B','C','D']), ignore_index=True) #works as you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Series` for row insertion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df = df.append(pd.Series([None]*2), ignore_index=True)
df["col1"][0] = 3.28
```

`df` looks like:

```
   col1 col2
0  3.28  NaN
```