# Appending row to pandas DF adds 0 column - clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I found the thread located here:

[Appending row to pandas df adds 0 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917108/appending-row-to-pandas-dataframe-adds-0-column)

but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Q':['chair', 'desk', 'monitor', 'chair'], 'R':['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple'], 'S': ['english', 'german', 'spanish', 'english']})

df4

         Q       R        S
0    chair     red  english
1     desk    blue   german
2  monitor  yellow  spanish
3    chair  purple  english


>> df5 = df4

>>> df5 = df5.append(['Q'] * 2, ignore_index=True)

>>> df5

         Q       R        S    0
0    chair     red  english  NaN
1     desk    blue   german  NaN
2  monitor  yellow  spanish  NaN
3    chair  purple  english  NaN
4      NaN     NaN      NaN    Q
5      NaN     NaN      NaN    Q
>>>
```

In my particular case, why did it add the 0 column? My initial DF is not empty.

Comment: Because you aren't specifying columns that the new values belong to.  Try with `df4.append([{'Q': 'Q'}] * 2, ignore_index=True)` to see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help page for pandas append states:
"Append rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a new object. Columns not in this frame are added as new columns."

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

in your case, you do not any supply column name(s), so new is(are) created.

Many ways to append a new row. One way:

```
df5 = df5.append({'Q':'Q', 'R':'Q', 'S':'Q'}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to append the list `['Q', 'Q']` to a dataframe with 3 columns. This is ambiguous.

Since it's not at all clear, Pandas takes the decision to pass `['Q', 'Q']` to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor before appending:

```
out1 = df5.append(pd.DataFrame(['Q'] * 2), ignore_index=True)
out2 = df5.append(['Q'] * 2, ignore_index=True)

assert out1.equals(out2)  # no error, i.e. these are equal
```

If you are still confused, trying printing the dataframe constructed from a single list:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(['Q'] * 2))

   0
0  Q
1  Q
```

Since no column names are specified, you have a column labeled `0`. When appending to a dataframe with different columns, you will necessarily see an additional column in the result.